# Python's dir() and help() equivalents in Swift REPL

Tags: swift, lldb

Just installed Swift on Ubuntu and was pleasantly surprised that executing `swift` runs a language shell (aka REPL), similar to Python's interactive shell.

To get a feel of the Swift language, which is new to me, I wanted to declare a few objects and see what methods they provide. In Python this is achieved by built-in function `dir(object)`, which returns names of attributes of an object. If you call it without arguments, it returns the list of variable and module names in the current local scope. – Both of these behaviors are very useful in the shell.

Python shell also has a very useful `help()` function, which invokes the built-in help system. By calling `help(object)`, you can read Python reference on the class of the object.

**Are there any equivalents of Python's help() and dir() inside Swift REPL?**

More specifically:

- Can I get the list of currently declared variables?
- Can I see the list of object methods in the shell (REPL)?
- Can I read object reference in the shell?

(If it helps, I have Swift version 4.2.1, LLDB version 6.0.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swift doesn't have the methods like `help()`　but you can use the lldb commands.
you can input `:` in Swift REPL for the shell to switch to LLDB mode.

> Can I see the list of object methods in the shell (REPL)?
>   `type lookup ClassNameOfInstance`
>
> Can I get the list of currently declared variables?
>   `image lookup -rs lldb_expr`
>
> Can I read object reference in the shell?
>   `expression -l swift -- instanceName`

use `c` command to exit LLDB mode.

addition:

- When you define a variables in Swift REPL, Swift Repl make modules such as `$__lldb_expr2`, `$__lldb_expr3` for each.
- If you would like to know lldb commands, you can use `help` command in lldb mode.

Comment: By object reference I meant documentation for a single object. Like if you type `help([1,2,3])` in Python shell, you will see documentation for list object. Other than that, thanks, it is what I was looking for.